# How to add several annotations?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I want to display several pins in map view. So I do:

```
let smth = [Smth(title: "Title 1", 
        locationName: "Street 1", 
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.2345965, longitude: 76.8907758)),
    Smth(title: "Title 2", 
        locationName: "Street 2",
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.2059723, longitude: 76.9012738))]
```

then:

```
mapView.addAnnotation(smth)
```

but it shows this error:

```
        Argument type '[Smth]' does not conform to expected type 'MKAnnotation'.
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this:

```
mapView.addAnnotations(smth)
```

Arrays require the method **"addAnnotations"**, not **"addAnnotation"**.